# Azure storage files force download to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage

I have my files stored in Azure File System and here are the requirements -

1. User should be able to view the documents without downloading it to the local

   - This is working fine for pdf but not any other mime types
   - I tried setting `Content-Type`,`Content-Disposition` (in azure file properties but no luck) and also iframe.
2. User should be able to edit the doc online without downloading.

   - I don't think this is possible just with Azure and have to integrate with One Drive may be? Correct me if I am wrong?

I would really appreciate any inputs/thoughts.

Comment: What type of file and what content-type?

Comment: pdf ,docx,xlsx,xls,doc etc

Comment: Is mapping a network drive to Azure File Storage an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a viable option but using Storage Accounts in Azure, you can map these accounts as a network drives to any client machine. So they would be able to access these files via File Explorer.

This [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/11/30/step-by-step-setting-up-azure-smb-file-share/) covers the basic steps in setting it up.

Unfortunately for anyone who wishes to use this feature, they need to be on Windows 8 (or above) to be able to map a network drive successfully as it uses [SMB3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2709568/new-smb-3.0-features-in-the-windows-server-2012-file-server).

If this option is a no go I will delete the post.

Comment: Thanks Kevchadders! Unfortunately we cannot guarantee that the users are on Windows 8. So I dont think we can go in that route .

Comment: To confirm, its windows 8 and above, but appreciate there will be a lot of users on windows 7 and below still. Users on those lower versions can user Storage Explorer which is a free offering (http://storageexplorer.com/) from Microsoft and view those files via that method but its adding another level of access which isn't ideal

Comment: Yeah! checking if AWS has the feature to edit/view files online.

Comment: @Nimz, did you get anywhere with editing in the browser? We have a similar requirement.  I see Edge now allows adding comments / highlighting when opening a PDF blob (application/pdf content type), but even when the SAS gives RW access, it forces a download when saving.